# airflow ui log error after deploying on kubernetes while using celery workers

Tags: kubernetes, celery, airflow, kubernetes-helm, bitnami

After deploying [BITNAMI HELM chart for AIRFLOW](https://github.com/bitnami/charts/tree/master/bitnami/airflow), on kubernetes cluster, ALTHOUGH EVERYTHING WORKS, logging is still unreachable.

Turns out that helm chat that is being used to deploy is using a headless service for communication between celery workers and is not able to show me logs.

I have set the hostname_callable setting right, and yet, LOGS ALWAYS PICK UP THE NAME OF HEADLESS SERVICE as their hostname, but, not the DNS name.

```
*** Log file does not exist: /opt/bitnami/airflow/logs/secondone/s3files/2020-06-19T10:35:00+00:00/1.log
*** Fetching from: http://mypr-afw-worker-1.mypr-afw-headless.mynamespace.svc.cluster.local:8793/log/secondone/s3files/2020-06-19T10:35:00+00:00/1.log
*** Failed to fetch log file from worker. HTTPConnectionPool(host='mypr-afw-worker-1.mypr-afw-headless.mynamespace.svc.cluster.local', port=8793): Max retries exceeded with url: /log/secondone/s3files/2020-06-19T10:35:00+00:00/1.log (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f12917f5630>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused',))
```

Any help in this regard would be appreciated! thanks!

Answer (score 0):

How are you setting the hostname, it seems you need to pass them as an array:

```yaml
## The list of hostnames to be covered with this ingress record.
## Most likely this will be just one host, but in the event more hosts are needed, this is an array
##
hosts:
  - name: airflow.local
    path: /
```

or `--set ingress.hosts[0].name=airflow.local --set ingress.hosts[0].path=/` in the `helm install` command